# Realm - Failed to connect to endpoint ':::9080': Connection refused

Tags: realm

I am getting the below error when starting the Realm object server. I am running the server on Mac.

Realm Mobile Platform version is 1.8.1

`2017-07-08T09:48:06.362Z - info: Logging to console at level 'info'.
2017-07-08T09:48:06.438Z - info: Realm Object Server sync engine listening on 127.0.0.1:27800.
2017-07-08T09:48:06.484Z - info: permission: Seed permission-Realms
2017-07-08T09:48:06.496Z - info: Realm Object Server web server listening on 127.0.0.1:27080.
2017-07-08T09:48:06.498Z - info: http proxy listening on :::9080.
2017-07-08T09:48:06.503Z - info: client: Opening Realm file: /Users/vkuppusamy/Documents/realm-mobile-platform/realm-object-server/object-server/root_dir/internal_data/auth.realm
2017-07-08T09:48:06.503Z - info: client: Connection[1]: Session[1]: Starting session for '/Users/vkuppusamy/Documents/realm-mobile-platform/realm-object-server/object-server/root_dir/internal_data/auth.realm'
2017-07-08T09:48:06.503Z - info: client: Connection[1]: Resolving ':::9080'
2017-07-08T09:48:06.503Z - info: client: Connection[1]: Connecting to endpoint ':::9080' (1/1)
2017-07-08T09:48:06.503Z - error: client: Connection[1]: Failed to connect to endpoint ':::9080': Connection refused
2017-07-08T09:48:06.503Z - error: client: Connection[1]: Failed to connect to ':::9080': All endpoints failed
2017-07-08T09:48:06.504Z - info: client: Opening Realm file: /Users/vkuppusamy/Documents/realm-mobile-platform/realm-object-server/object-server/realm-object-server/listener/__admin.realm
2017-07-08T09:48:06.504Z - info: client: Connection[2]: Session[2]: Starting session for '/Users/vkuppusamy/Documents/realm-mobile-platform/realm-object-server/object-server/realm-object-server/listener/_`

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore that - it's likely due to clients trying to connect before the server has initialized completely.